# Problem with resizing a form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm drawing an image in a form. When the image is too wide, I want to increase the width of the form. Here's how I do it in the constructor:

```
    ImageForm(String^ _path, int _w, int _h)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(this->ClientSize.Width <= _w)
        {
            this->ClientSize.Width = _w+2;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Even if the if-branch gets executed, the width of the form remains unchanged.

Comment: You've been tinkering with other properties I think, judging from previous questions.  Make sure AutoSize is False for example.

Answer (score 0):

Things that you draw are not considers clients since they are not objects, you can notice that if you resize the form manually, they will disappear. this is why we use PictureBox for drawing.

Hope that it's useful.